# Printing each item in a multidimensional list on a new line doesn't work

Tags: list, python-3.x

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
maximum = list([[x[0], x[-1]] for x in score_list])
  print ("Here are the student's higest scores:")

for i in maximum:
  print(maximum)
```

Maximum contains:

```
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
```

I am adding some values from the front and end of maximum and converting them to a list. I am trying to print them out all on a new line with the for loop but it seems to just print

```
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
[['Andy', 8], ['Bill', 7], ['Steve', 7], ['Andrew', 10], ['Ted', 9], ['Lisa', 10]]
```

instead of each value once like:

```
['Andy',8]
['Steve',7]
['Bill',7]
(and so on)
```

I've googled for a solution to this but everywhere I go I see the for loop that I have above yet it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in maximum:
    print (i)
```

Comment: Literally, I am such an idiot. I have no idea why I did not notice that in the beggining